# Wrong height of div image wrapper with percentage width values

Tags: css, html, image

I want to wrap an image into an HTML `div` and since I want this to be fully scalable with the size of the window, I want to set the width of the `div` in percentage as follows:

**HTML**

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <img src="http://openclipart.org/people/netalloy/rally-car.svg" />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
#wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
}

#wrapper img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

The image should determine the height of its container. This is because the image width is set to 100% and the image height is calculated accordingly, maintaining the correct aspect ratio.

The result is visible on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lorenzopolidori/5BN4g/15/).

My questions are:

1. Why do all modern browsers render the wrapper `div` 5px taller than the inner image?
2. How can I get rid of this 5px gap, while still setting all the sizes in percentage and *without* using JavaScript?

Surprisingly, this happens in

- Chrome (21.0.1180.89)
- Firefox (15.0.1) and
- IE8

while IE7 renders it correctly, matching the height of the `div` with the height of the image.

Comment: 5 different answers that all works!!!

Comment: indeed! thanks everyone, I think it's just the matter of what one likes more now.

Comment: I think you should combine between the vertical align and the line-height. Those are the most semantic (if I may say) solutions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, fiddling about, I found a good possible solution:

```css
#wrapper img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px dashed red;
}
```

Changing from the default `inline` display to a `block` display eliminates the `line-height` problem straight away.

This approach is also *semantically* correct because in this case what we really want is a single image wrapped in a `div` without any other elements in it, so the concept of `line-height` needs to be completely wiped off by displaying the image as a block.

It works on all major browsers: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/lorenzopolidori/5Cpf2/3/)

Answer (score 2):

Check [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5BN4g/29/) out. It's a `line-height` issue.

You need:

```css
#wrapper {
    width: 60%;
    background-color: #aaa;
    margin: 50px auto;
    line-height: 0;
}
    
#wrapper img {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px dashed red;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

​
I used `box-sizing` to make sure the `width` of the image doesn't overflow the container.

Answer (score 1):

Add `vertical-align: top` in your `img` tag's CSS as follows:

```css
#wrapper img {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px dashed red;
    vertical-align: top; // Add this line
}
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5BN4g/28/)**

Comment: This one works ... check my solution I went through different approach!

Comment: @AhmadAlfy you used to border-box nice example but it's work only latest browser and this is css3 part ..........

Comment: I used border-box only for the demonstration only.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should set `align` property to force the browser to show the `img` tag correctly.

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <img align="center" src="http://openclipart.org/image/800px/svg_to_png/74557/rally-car.png" />
</div>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/afshinprofe/5BN4g/24/)

Comment: It works, though I need to change the HTML for a style-related problem rather than just the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I think is because it doesn't see as a Table

i added the display:table in your code

And it looks fine now, check the link

[Example Display Table](http://jsfiddle.net/5BN4g/32/)

Comment: This doesn't work on IE8. Also, displaying an image as a table is not *semantically* correct. It's much better to display it as a block, which is also supported by IE.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that an image -- the `<img>` tag, to be exact -- is an inline element. All you need to do is set `display: block` on the image and the extra padding goes away. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5BN4g/48/).

Comment: Thanks, this is the same conclusion I came to in my answer.